# How to retrieve a list that defined in a method with an asynchronous call?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a new Tecnology: Beacon. I use Jaalee beacons, and I program with Android. My problem is that: when i use for the first time the beacon, I use a method that scan the all device, but my personal device, appears always (I think it's normal) and for this I try to add this in ArrayList. 
But when i want read this arrayList it's null beacause I think that the scan it's not compleate.

```
 bledevice = new  ArrayList<BLEDevice>();

 beaconManager.setDeviceDiscoverListener(new DeviceDiscoverListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBLEDeviceDiscovered(final BLEDevice device) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                       
                    Log.i("Jaalee", " Bluetooth discovered:" + device.getMacAddress());
                    logToDisplay("Beacon trovato: \n " +
                                    "MAC " + device.getMacAddress() + "\n" +
                                    "Nome " + device.getName() + "\n" +
                                    "RSSI " + device.getRssi() + "\n");
                    bledevice.add(device);
                }
            });
        }
    });

for (BLEDevice item : bledevice) {
    Log.i("LIST"," check :" + item.getMacAddress());
    logToDisplay(item.toString());
}
```

In my opinion, I should use a CallBack in Java, but I don't know if there is the  right way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at AsyncTask and its methods onPreExecute, doInBackground and onPostExecute.

So you can add the data in the doInBackground() and then run the loop in onPostExecute.